# selecting the latest record from multiple tables in one database (MYSQL PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have school mysql db with 15 tables (15 class rooms), each table has unified fields/simple data like this: ID, DATE, TIME, CLASSROOM_NO, STUDENTS_ALL, STUDENTS_CURRENT, COMMENTS

approach is to be able to keep updating this data all the time through php form that increment that db, that is fine, it is working fine.

in another php page, i have display.php that shows me only the latest record added, so i can know the latest update done to this classroom, and this is also fine, it is exactly what i need, here is my code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","classroom","mypsassword","mysqluser");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all,     student_current,comments FROM classroom_1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {

 echo "<b>Room:</b> " . $row['classroom_no'] . "<br>";
 echo "<b>All students:</b> " . $row['students_all'] . "<br>";
 echo "<b>Available students:</b> " . $row['students_current'] . "<br>";
 echo "<b>Absent:</b> ";
 echo floatval($row['students_all'])  -  floatval($row['students_current']);
 echo "<br>";
 echo "<b>Updated on:</b> " . $row['date'] ."<br>";
 echo "<b>Update time:</b> " . $row['time']."<br>" ;

  }

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

now, i have no problem in achieving and retrieving the latest update from each classroom in one page... what i struggle for is to select the latest record from each table and then display them all accordingly in the same page... so to have a php page say all_classrooms.php

and to show all classrooms together (only the latest record update from each table) in one page, so i am not able to understand how to select the sql query from all tables in the same time and have it limited to the latest record...

my tables are in sequencal orders like this: 
classroom_1
classroom_2
classrrom_3

please advise

Comment: I would suggest that you normalize your database design. Put all the classroom data into one table with a column to show what classroom any particular row relates to.

Comment: Why have you got 15 tables for 15 classrooms? You should have three tables - classroom info, students, bookings (or appropriate name)

Comment: So each of tables has a column CLASSROOM_NO and each table has all the same data in that column per table?

Comment: yes LIUFA, exactly, i want it this way so i can update only one table at the time

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Kickstart: I would suggest that you normalize your database design. Put all the classroom data into one table with a column to show what classroom any particular row relates to.

Other (workaround) solution that I would not recoment, would be to [create a view](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-views-mysql.aspx). That looks like

```
CREATE VIEW allData AS
SELECT * from Classroom1
UNION ALL SELECT * from Classroom2
....
```

and then write select from this view.

Comment: thank you again LIUFA, i am unfortunately this is beyond my experience i can't understand it, will try some other basic ways to do, sorry for my english too i know i could be annoying when come to make you guys understand the need :(

Comment: @MikeDerik I have added link on to how to create view, in simple words if you will be selecting same data from multiple tables you usually create a view for that.

Comment: absolutely interesting, you gave me huge homework to learn, thanks dude, will try to understand it and apply accordingly if could, appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to redesign your database with one table for the classrooms, another for the classes (many rows per classroom), etc.

However if that isn't possible you would need something like this:-

```
SELECT classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments
FROM
(
    SELECT '1' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_1
    UNION
    SELECT '2' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_2
    UNION
    SELECT '3' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_3
    UNION
    SELECT '4' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_4
    UNION
    SELECT '5' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_5
    UNION
    SELECT '6' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_6
    UNION
    SELECT '7' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_7
    UNION
    SELECT '8' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_8
    UNION
    SELECT '9' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_9
    UNION
    SELECT '10' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_10
    UNION
    SELECT '11' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_11
    UNION
    SELECT '12' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_12
    UNION
    SELECT '13' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_13
    UNION
    SELECT '14' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_14
    UNION
    SELECT '15' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_15
) Sub1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT classroom, MAX(id) AS maxid
    FROM
    (
        SELECT '1' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_1
        UNION
        SELECT '2' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_2
        UNION
        SELECT '3' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_3
        UNION
        SELECT '4' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_4
        UNION
        SELECT '5' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_5
        UNION
        SELECT '6' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_6
        UNION
        SELECT '7' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_7
        UNION
        SELECT '8' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_8
        UNION
        SELECT '9' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_9
        UNION
        SELECT '10' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_10
        UNION
        SELECT '11' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_11
        UNION
        SELECT '12' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_12
        UNION
        SELECT '13' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_13
        UNION
        SELECT '14' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_14
        UNION
        SELECT '15' AS classroom, id, date, time, classroom_no, students_all, student_current, comments FROM classroom_15
    ) Sub3
    GROUP BY classroom
) Sub2
ON Sub1.classroom = Sub2.classroom AND Sub1.id = Sub2.maxid
```

Note that I have added a fixed classroom column in the UNION. This might duplicate the value of classroom_no.

It is also concerning that there is a column called students_all. That suggests that you have a column containing a list of the students. If so it would be far better to split that off into another table which could have many rows for each class (one per student in a class)

Comment: i will try this, as i can't change the db design now, i want it this way to be able to update the information of any classroom anytime, and may update only one classroom anytime,, i will try this, but if there is something simipler is also appreciated... my idea was to put all 15 connections under each other on one page, so it will give the 15 classrooms in the same page yet maintain the last record from each classroom data... but i know it is not recommended to have 15 connections in the same page! or what you think?

Comment: No reason to use more than one connection, unless you are using a database class that over writes one query with the next. You can use a single connection and then just pass the resulting $con around (if you need to access a 2nd table when half way through processing a 1st table then just use a different variable to put the result of `mysqli_query(....)` into). You could make the above SQL simpler to use by creating a view based on it but that would not help performance at all (probably slow it down a touch).

Comment: well, i really appreciate your help, i am not that expert to do what you advised, but will try my best to have a big page shows in each row one classroom data, that is the purpose, and this row reflects the latest update of that table (classroom data)... i do see it complicated because i am not that expert :) although i could display the latest update for one classroom using LIMIT 1 and that was achievement, now when comes to an overview of the school and want to show all classrooms data in one page (the latest record from each table only) i see it hard cz i lack of experience, keep trying...

Comment: I will try and explain what the above sql does. What it does is has many queries, one against each rooms table, with the results unioned together. It uses the results of this one along with MAX(id) / GROUP BY classroom. This gets the maximum id for each classroom. It then performs the large query again and joins the results against the results of the max id for each classroom. This gets the other details for each max id per classroom to put them out. You could make the large query into a view, and a view just allows you to use the results of a query as though it were a table.

Comment: thanks a lot Kickstart, appreciated your efforts really, will do my best to understand and apply accordingly.